# Best practice when using multiline expression inside a data.table

Tags: r, coding-style, data.table

Let's say we want to perform an "intricate series" of operations on a data.table using `{}` inside the `j` of a data.table, a la:

```
data(mtcars)
carName <- row.names(mtcars)
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[, car_name := carName]

mtcars[, {
  num_cars <- length(unique(car_name))
  avg_disp <- mean(disp)
  avg_hp <- mean(hp)
  eff <- mpg/wt
  data.table(num_cars, avg_disp, avg_hp,
             avg_eff = mean(eff), median_eff = median(eff))
}, keyby = cyl]
```

I understand that this can be performed in several steps:

```
mtcars[, `:=`(num_cars = length(unique(car_name)),
              avg_disp = mean(disp),
              avg_hp = mean(hp),
              eff = mpg/wt),
       keyby = cyl]

mtcars[, `:=`(avg_eff = mean(eff), median_eff = median(eff)), keyby = cyl]
mtcars[, .SD[1,list(num_cars, avg_disp, avg_hp, avg_eff, median_eff)], 
       keyby = cyl]
```

But I'm interested in know what the most idiomatic way (read: best practices) way to perform this kind of thing is.

Is it generally frowned down upon to work inside `{}` in the `j` of a data.table?

Comment: No. It's perfectly fine to work with `{}` within the `j` expression and even encouraged if this could save you memory useage/ speed things up/ make your code clearer. One thing though, don't use `data.table` within the `j` expression just do `.(num_cars, avg_disp, avg_hp, avg_eff = mean(eff), median_eff = median(eff))` instead.

Comment: I find that using `.()` has `R CMD check` complain at me... Is there a way around this?

Comment: `list()`. Which `data.table` version are you using btw?

Comment: data.table version (>= 1.9.4) (just upgraded to 1.9.6)

Comment: Ok, strange it is not passing `R CMD check`. `list()` should work though.

Comment: So, using `.()` yields the following note: `sampleFxn: no visible global function definition for ‘.’`...

Comment: Yeah, `.()` will only work if it makes up the whole expression `j=.(...)` not `j={...; .(...)}`. It's just a shortcut to `list()` in that special case, as far as I've seen.